# change the image doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, thumbnails

here is my javasript:

```
$(function() {
    $(".image2").click(function() {
        var image = $(this).attr("rel");
        $('#random_img').hide();
        $('#random_img').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#random_img').attr('src') == image;
        var image2 = $('#random_img').attr('src');
        $("#thumb2 a img").removeClass("open");
        $("#thumb2 a[rel='" + image2 + "'] img").addClass("open");
        return false;
    });
});
```

here is my html:

```
<div id="image2">
    <img id="random_img" src="/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/indigovision.jpg" height="420" width="964" />
</div>
<div id="thumb2">
    <a href="#" rel="/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/canon.jpg" class="image2">
        <img title="Canon" class="slider_thumb" src="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/t_flash/t1.png" border="0"/></a>
    <a href="#" rel="/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/indigovision.jpg" class="image2">
        <img title="IndigoVision" class="slider_thumb" src="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/t_flash/t2.png" border="0"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

when i click on a thumbnail, the animation fadeIn and hide works, but the image is not changed...why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank u @Shurdoof! now everything works fine!
here is the solution:

```
$('#random_img').attr('src',image);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the image, specify second argument to `attr`:

```
$('#random_img').attr('src', image);
```

Instead of this which won't work:

```
$('#random_img').attr('src') = image;
```

[Check out the second version of `attr` here for more info.](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

---

You are also not storing `src` in your `image` variable but its `rel` attribute here:

```
var image = $(this).attr("rel");
```

Which should be:

```
var image = $(this).attr("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Also, you are using equality operator `==` where you may usually use assignment operator `=`. This won't work with `.attr` method though..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#random_img').attr('src') == image;
```

should be

```
$('#random_img').attr('src') = image;
```